# Best Azure Service for Application

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I have an application that fetches data from a remote server and sends the data to my server (ASP.NET 6). I want the application to run once every 24 hours, and ideally at the same time every day.

My initial thought was to host it using Azure App Service and keep the app running, but the free tier doesn't support the Always On Feature.

Assuming I host my app using Azure App Service, is it possible to invoke it using an Azure Function that would ping the app service once every 24 hours, allowing it to run?

What is the best service or combination of free services that I can use to achieve that?

Note: I am new to Azure

Comment: A timer triggered azure function that runs every 24h is an option.

Comment: @PeterBons you mean to run my application as an azure function?

Comment: Yes, if it is a short (less than 5 minutes) process every 24h

Comment: @PeterBons, its a pretty heavy process, a lot of data parsing using regex

Comment: What is the likely total duration of your data parsing? You could make your logic as 'activity' steps and make use of `Durable` functions that are triggered once every 24hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is splitting the app into smaller azure functions, each with its own purpose. I also created an azure logic app that handles the rest of the logic and calls the azure functions when required.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation totally suit for Azure Function. There are two options

1. `Time Tigger Azure Function` :- logic write this azure function and Schedule for every 24.
2. `Durable Azure Function` :-Durable one use for complex logic

[Click Here For More Details for Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview)

Move your all logic fro app service to azure function then host and schedule azure function.

Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up creating an azure logic app that calls azure functions which represent parts of what used to be my app

Comment: why did you use azure logic app. you can only  implementation this only by azure function.